# Linker Error with CMake and Point Cloud Library

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors, point-cloud-library

I have tried to install and add PointCloud Library into my Project but I always got linker errors. Here is my Cmake file :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(OpenCV-BATest)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(SOURCES regression.h)

find_package(Qt5Core)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
find_package(PCL 1.3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS common io)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${PCL_COMMON_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_IO_LIBRARIES})
```

Funny thing is the OpenCV lib, which i did the same way, didnt create any"undefined reference to.." errors, but only the PCL library.
[image]

Comment: show us the "linker errors"

Comment: Sorry , done @HumamHelfawi

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, this should be included

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

instead.